# Flask/Jinja2 Continue statement

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

Im working on a simple app, specifically the "view_cart" functionality where a user can view what items they've added to their checkout cart. I have the simple cart working, but am having trouble displaying it the way I want. Specifically, for multiples of the same item, I would like there to be a quantity with a price next to that item when you view the cart, versus what i have now where each item displays individually. e.g "beef 1, beef 1, beef 1, ham 1, ham 1. My goal is "beef 3, ham 2".

I wanted to use a for loop with Jinja but apparently break/continue(if quantity greater than 1) is not supported. Any suggestions on how to make this work without that functionality is much appreciated. Current code below :

```
{% include "navtemp.html" %} 

{% for i in items %}


  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-3">

           <img src="/static/{{ i[0][3] }}" style="width:200px;height:300px;"></div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
        <p>{{ i[0][1] }}</p>
        <p>${{ i[0][4] }}</p>
        <p>Qty: {{ items.count(i) }}</p>
        <form method="post" action="{{ url_for('pricing',cartQty=cartQty) }}">
            <input type="hidden" name="{{ i[0][1] }}" id="remove" value="remove">
            <h5><button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Remove</button></h5>
        </form>
    </div>

</div>
```

{% endfor %}

Answer (score 0):

In your view code you should group your items:

```
import itertools as it, operator as op

l = [[0,'beef','a.png',9.99],[1,'ham','b.png',7.99],[2,'beef','a.png',9.99],
     [3,'ham','b.png',7.99],[4,'beef','a.png',9.99]] 
l.sort(key=op.itemgetter(1))
items = []
for k,g in it.groupby(l,op.itemgetter(1,2,3)): 
    items.append(list(k) + [sum(1 for i in g)])
```

Then `items` is:

```
[['beef', 'a.png', 9.99, 3], ['ham', 'b.png', 7.99, 2]]
```

And then you'd need to adjust your index values in your template.